# How to start java process with user defined name?

Tags: java

When I start new java process by default is having name 'java',
I can see the process with name 'java' in task manager.

What I want is I want to start process with another name rather than 'java'

so, How to start java process with user defined name rather than 'java' or 'javaw' ?

Comment: or [How can I give my Java application a unique process name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152356/how-can-i-give-my-java-application-a-unique-process-name?rq=1)

Comment: or this :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057247/how-can-i-set-the-process-name-for-a-java-program