# Is there a way to set the description field in task manager?

Tags: java

How can I set the description field in Task Manager (Windows 10+) to my program. I want to define a description or name in task manager not just java.exe.

Right now it says `Java(TM) Platform SE binary` in the description field and java.exe in the name field.

[Description Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxsZZ.png)

Comment: you can't, afaik. It's not your application that is detected by windows, but the jvm in which your application runs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152356/how-can-i-give-my-java-application-a-unique-process-name

Comment: You can go to the "Select columns" menu entry and choose to display the command line. Then you can find your java application name on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy your java.exe into the same folder. Rename it as myApp.exe and run it as you run the Java.

On cmd:

```
myApp -jar myJar.jar
```

Comment: .... how little sense does this make? copy your java.exe to anywhere, and it won't work, since it'll be looking for the resources of the jre on it's path.

Comment: Read carefully, not copy to "anywhere", copy "into the same folder" which contains JRE! I am currently using this in several servers with no problem.

Comment: and your jre has "myApp.exe" in it?

Comment: Yes, works well. Just try on cmd: myApp -version