# How to give the java process a name in the operating system (other than java)

Tags: java

I'm playing around with some microservices and running them on my laptop, simply assigning each micro-service a new port. The problem is that I'd like to restart one of them I have to close them all because in the operating system the processes are all called java. And although I sometime can guess that the last started have the highest pid etc is isn't exacly a safe bet...

So, is there a way to start a java-application and assign it a name in the operating system? Perhaps something like

`java --Dos.name MyFirstService -jar MyJar.jar.`

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @Gowtham I'd prefer if java handled it and not by wrapping the command in an operating system specific command. But right now I'm running on windows, but if I'm happy after playing for a while it will run on linux.

Comment: Another possible solution to your problem might be using something that shows you the complete commandline, not just process name. On Windows for example [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to be able to differentiate between different java programs you can use the jps command that gives you a list of all java processes and running your program with

```
java -Dname=myFirstService -cp  myFirstService.jar some.client.main.MyFirstService
```

then if you do a:

```
jps -v
```

You will see your process correctly.

If you need to change the process name at the OS level I recommend you use http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 9):

Under Windows, you can't (unless installing some kind of posix subsystem).

Under Linux, you could use `exec` command with the `-a "newName"` option to alias the process you wish to spawn.

Like

```
exec -a "myJar" /path/to/java -jar /path/to/jar.jar
```